# Spring boot Hazelcast SQL Predicate

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast cache in the my spring boot application..

If i go with IMap<Key,Value> means I can directly use SqlPredicate method for querying..

But how to pass HazelCast SQl Queries in the Spring boot application..

Is there any annotation for passing queries?

If there means how to pass particular methods?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get access to your `IMap` instance, you can simply pass your instance of `SqlPredicate` to the `IMap#values` method:

```
IMap<String, String> map = ...;
Collection<String> employees = map.values(new SqlPredicate("active AND age < 30"));
```